# Is there a (RAD) tool for dynamic web creation (php + html )

Tags: ide, wysiwyg, server-side, rad

Is there any tool something like access or front page that combines? 
The server side also ( php ) for none programmers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such tool exist, but there are a number of IDE that can ease the development process:

http://www.activestate.com/komodo/
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Answer (score 0):

I htink dreamweaver can generate php code, but I don't know about anything like that which generates complex custom applications...

Comment: PHP Dreamweaver code is a joke. each statement has a opening and closing PHP tag. Its for people that have no clue what PHP is and want to use it.